# How can I install KODI (Docker version) on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, kodi

On my ubuntu server, I want to configure some services using only theirs docker images, one of them is Kodi, an open source media player. I installed and run it using the following commands:

```
root@server:/home/user# docker pull celedhrim/kodi-server

root@server:/home/user# sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
celedhrim/kodi-server   latest    ba83bcb40db1   7 months ago   988MB

root@server:/home/user# docker run -d --restart="always" --net=host -v /path/to/kodi-server-profile:/usr/share/kodi/portable_data celedhrim/kodi-server

root@server:/home/user# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2811/kodi.bin <--- KODI!!      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2042/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      738/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2042/sshd: /usr/sbi
```

now, from an another PC I tried to get access via https:/SERVER_IP:9090, but it didn't work. the web page returned me a "connection refused". what am I doing wrong?

in the "hub docker" there is a guide, but I can't understand the first points:
https://hub.docker.com/r/celedhrim/kodi-server

Comment: Try using [docker-kodi](https://github.com/ehough/docker-kodi), described as "Dockerized Kodi with audio and video".

Comment: What step exactly are you confused by?

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't understand the first and the second point. point 1: "Prepare a full kodi profile with the regular GUI version ( windows or linux )". I didn't ever use Kodi, I just installed it on my Ubuntu server and from here I can only use the Terminal. speaking about the other things explained below, .. to be honest I really don't know what he is taliking, maybe it is clear for who already know Kodi. point 2: "Make a copy of the ~/.kodi directory ( destination doesn't matter , this is just an example)" I don't have this directory, and why should I copy /.kodi to another destination?

Comment: @Ramhound more or less I only understand the guide from the third point, but, as I already explained in my question, I can't get access to KODI via HTTP or HTTPS, even if the TCP port 9090 is in listen mode for KODI.

Comment: @TurboC - So "docker pull celedhrim/kodi-server" pulls the current stable docker container for Kodi successfully?  That command is step 3. while step 4 would be `docker run -d --restart="always" --net=host -v /path/to/kodi-server-profile:/usr/share/kodi/portable_data celedhrim/kodi-server` so which step fails?

Comment: @Ramhound you described exactly what I already did and I wrote it in my question too. I just follow the step 3 and 4. so, which step fails? I don't know, .. from `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` I can see a TCP service active on 9090 port but I can't get access from HTTP or HTTPS (my browser says: connection refused).